# ignore KeyError while subsetting pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I have a pandas dataframe df with columns `city1`, `city2`, `city3`, `city4`, `city5`. I have a list `my_cities = ["city1","city3","city10"]`. I want to subset df according to the columns in `my_cities`. When I do,

```
my_cities = ["city1","city3","city10"]

df_my_cities = df[my_cities]
```

I get the error `KeyError: "['city10'] not in index"`

How can I tell the code to keep proceeding if an element from `my_cities` in not in `df`?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) between all columns and `list`:

```
df_my_cities = df[df.columns.intersection(my_cities)]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city1':['s', 'e'],
                   'city2':['e','f'],
                   'city3':['f','g'],
                   'city4':['r','g'],
                   'city5':['t','m']})

print (df)
  city1 city2 city3 city4 city5
0     s     e     f     r     t
1     e     f     g     g     m

my_cities = ["city1","city3","city10"]
df_my_cities = df[df.columns.intersection(my_cities)]
print (df_my_cities)
  city1 city3
0     s     f
1     e     g
```

Alternatively [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
df_my_cities = df[np.intersect1d(df.columns, my_cities)]
print (df_my_cities)
  city1 city3
0     s     f
1     e     g
```